# Use different prefix for const and non-const private members in editorconfig

Tags: c#, visual-studio, constants, editorconfig

I want to use m_ for non-const private members and c_ for const ones. However, editorconfig doesn't allow me to specify a rule for non-const members only as far as I can see. The following doesn't work, regardless of the order of specification of private members in general or const ones:

```
# Prefix private/protected fields with m_
dotnet_naming_rule.prefix_private_members.symbols               = private_fields
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_kinds           = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_accessibilities = private;protected;protected_internal

dotnet_naming_rule.prefix_private_members.style                 = private_prefix_style
dotnet_naming_style.private_prefix_style.capitalization         = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style.private_prefix_style.required_prefix        = m_

dotnet_naming_rule.prefix_private_members.severity              = warning

# Prefix private/protected const fields with c_
dotnet_naming_rule.prefix_const_members.symbols                 = const_fields
dotnet_naming_symbols.const_fields.applicable_kinds             = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.const_fields.applicable_accessibilities   = private;protected;protected_internal
dotnet_naming_symbols.const_fields.required_modifiers           = const

dotnet_naming_rule.prefix_const_members.style                   = const_prefix_style
dotnet_naming_style.const_prefix_style.capitalization           = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style.const_prefix_style.required_prefix          = c_

dotnet_naming_rule.prefix_const_members.severity                = warning
```

What do I do? I also tried using Pascal case instead of c_ to distinguish const, but the conflict still occurs since the camel_case for fields in general conflicts with that.

Answer (score 4):

I got `PascalCase` for constant fields and `m_camelCase` for non-constant fields.

```
## constant fields should be PascalCase
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_should_be_pascal_case.severity = error
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_should_be_pascal_case.symbols  = constant_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_should_be_pascal_case.style    = pascal_case_style
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.applicable_kinds   = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.required_modifiers = const
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case_style.capitalization = pascal_case

# private fields should be m_camelCase
dotnet_naming_rule.camel_case_for_private_fields.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.camel_case_for_private_fields.symbols  = private_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.camel_case_for_private_fields.style    = camel_case_underscore_style

dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_accessibilities = private

dotnet_naming_style.camel_case_underscore_style.required_prefix = m_
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case_underscore_style.capitalization = camel_case
```

Different prefixes for non-constant and constant fields seems to be an [open issue (Editorconfig : Can't exclude const fields)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23391)