# Customize "quick fix" behaviour in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

I'm on Visual Studio for Mac 8.0.9 and would like to change the behaviour of several "quick fixes" (the options in the menu when I hit ALT + enter).

Specifically, I'd like to change the *Create and initialize field 'myParam'* option.

Right now it does this:

```cs
/// before quickfix
public class Test
{
    public Test(object myParam) { }
}

/// after quickfix:
public class Test
{
    public readonly object myParam
    public Test(object myParam)
    {
        this.myParam = myParam
    }
}
```

In our code base we're using underscores for private fields, as inspired by [these naming conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md). Therefore I'd like to change the behaviour to this:

```
/// after quickfix:
public class Test
{
    public readonly object _myParam
    public Test(object myParam)
    {
        _myParam = myParam
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

[Edit]

Things I tried:

- looked for an option like the one [described in the accepted answer
  here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52603580/4441216). Seems to be no UI option in VS Mac
- Tried configuring a `.editorconfig` file as described
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845892/4441216). Tried putting
  it in the solution root as well as one of the root of one of the
  containing project, but it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736659/how-do-i-customize-visual-studios-private-field-generation-shortcut-for-constru

Comment: "as inspired by [these naming conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md)." The naming conventions list "Field name" with no prefix. Granted it also says "Exception: you **can** prefix private fields with an underscore" but their conventions do not.

Comment: @MarcelN. That answer unfortunately does not apply to my question because I'm on VS Mac. Haven't found a similar option

Comment: What about the other answers, which use the Roslyn config file?

Comment: @MarcelN. I have to admit I should have included this in my main question. Please check the edited version

Comment: Weird, they say it supports basic editorconfig features + naming conventions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/editorconfig?view=vsmac-2019. Maybe you can check that you've followed all the steps there.

Comment: Jeez. Restarting VS did the trick :/