# editorconfig - how to specify underscore prefix for readonly private fields?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-formatting, editorconfig

I haven't been able to find anything on this online.

Is there any way to specify that an underscore prefix for readonly private fields should be added?

Ever since I started using an `editorconfig` file, Visual Studio will PascalCase the field when I choose the "Introduce read-only field" action.

[image: This is the action I am choosing]

Comment: I found this on another answer... Not sure if it is helpful `dotnet_naming_style.private_prefix_style.required_prefix = _`

Comment: Can you try the solution in this post? <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736659/how-do-i-customize-visual-studios-private-field-generation-shortcut-for-constru

Comment: Did you have any update for this issue? First of all, I agree with Sebastian's idea  and VS can customize naming rules and include prefixes. You can go to `Tools-->Options-->Text Editor-->C#(if you are using C#)-->Code Style-->Naming` to add a new rule.You can refer to that document for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer here solved my issue, as linked by Sebastian Brunner in the comments:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49428349/553609