# In Visual Studio 2022, how to make auto complete private field as camel case like _fieldName

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, visual-studio-2022

[image]
I have custom naming C# use CamelCase with added underscore in front like `fieldName` become `_fieldName`. But the problem is the autocomplete always use `fieldName` not generate `_fieldName`.

I already edit naming option C# on vs 2022 to `_fieldName` but the auto completion still use `fieldName`

Here is the example. You can see the auto completion want to write `animator` instead `_animator`
[image]

Comment: Why is there a red squiggle under `private`?

Comment: @Charlieface it's because I'm still writing above the line. You can see the gray `animator` where it's still invisible, if I press `Tab` it will complete then the red squiggle will gone. Anyway, do you know about how to make auto complete to follow Naming convention that I set on Settings?

Comment: I'm followed  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52603580/7247051 but not worked. I used Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.6.1. Maybe this config still override in .editorconfig?

Comment: I think that gray is just the new "AI powered" completion feature. It tends to adjust itself after you use it for a bit. Autocompletion is when you get a pop up list offering you options to select, and the options you are adjusting are for the right click hints

Comment: @Charlieface I see... But I have been using it everyday and always generate `fieldName`. I think I will ask on vs forum.

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for `Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.6.1`.

Edit `.editorconfig` file of your project with `notepad` and add this lines:

```
[*.{cs,vb}]
#### Naming styles ####

# Naming rules

# Other configurations in here
# ..

# Start underscores for private fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_with_underscore.symbols  = private_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_with_underscore.style    = prefix_underscore
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_with_underscore.severity = warning
# End underscores for private fields


# Symbol specifications

# Other configurations in here
# ..

# Start underscores for private fields
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_kinds           = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_accessibilities = private
# End underscores for private fields


# Naming styles

# Other configurations in here
# ..

# Start underscores for private fields
dotnet_naming_style.prefix_underscore.capitalization = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style.prefix_underscore.required_prefix = _
# End underscores for private fields
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I don't want right click and fix name violation, I just need the auto completion when press `Tab` and become `_fieldName`.